# tower.js with passport.js example

Tags: oauth, towerjs, passport.js

I am new to tower.js i want to integrate passport.js for the facebook authentication please any one can give me me a short but detail example how to to integrate login functionality and where to put the code.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that should definitely get you started:
[Tower.js with Passport demo app](https://github.com/viatropos/tower-authentication-example)

My understanding is that its still incomplete, but should at least give you a starting point.